# Can't get php 7.1 to work on apache 2.4 (FAMP)

Tags: apache-httpd, freebsd, php, php7

Running FreeBSD 11, I am having trouble getting Apache 2.4 to work with PHP 7.1.

1. Built apache24 from ports
2. Built php71 from ports
3. Added index.php to DirectoryIndex (httpd.conf):

   <IfModule dir_module>
       DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
   </IfModule>
4. Added the following to the end of httpd.conf:

   <FilesMatch .php$>
       SetHandler None
       ForceType text/plain
   </FilesMatch>
   <FilesMatch .phps$>
       SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
   </FilesMatch>

[index.php output](http://siso.godtnok.com/index.php)
PHP does not execute, still, and I am having trouble finding details and resources to figure this out, so I am hoping someone here can offer a bit of insight.

Answer (score 0):

Apache/PHP is handling `.php` files as text, because you told it to do it.

While your `.phps` handler is ok, you are telling Apache/PHP to handle `.php` files as text.

```
.php ->  SetHandler None ; ForceType text/plain

.phps$ -> SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
```

If you really want to use `.php` files as PHP scripts/programs, you need to setup it up with the same configuration as you have done with `.phps`

Comment: thank you for such quick response!

I should have caught that bit, but even after I changed the config, it still does not compile php code:

`<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>`

.. Any idea what I am missing? Might I have forgotten something when I compiled PHP71 and/or apache24?